# How to perform click in Selenium with autoplay video?

Tags: java, selenium, video, instagram, pause

I try to write a simple code in Java (Eclipse) with Selenium. The code has to find the Instagram Stories of a user and download them in my computer. When I open the stories window of a user I'm able to download all the photos but I find many problems with videos. To solve the problem I thought to click on "Pause" button and later get the "currentSrc" attribute but I'm not able to perform click() on "Pause" so the Instagram Stories keep going on and the program doesn't find the element. I try to play pause with executor:

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(30)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//*[contains(concat( \" \", @class, \" \" ), concat( \" \", \"_abm0\", \" \" ))])[1]")));
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", wait);
```

I tried with actions:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(wait).click().perform();
```

I even tried with only click():

```
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(30)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//*[contains(concat( \" \", @class, \" \" ), concat( \" \", \"_abm0\", \" \" ))])[1]")));
    wait.click();
```

I try to use different locator for example cssSelector but I think that the problem is the "autoplay=true" property of the Instagram Stories for videos. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved, it was my error in WebDriverWait condition of 30 seconds :))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).